# Callback every regular time interval in ODE solver of DifferentialEquations.jl in Julia

Tags: callback, event-handling, julia, ode

https://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/callback_functions.html

I am trying to mimic the first example of ContinuousCallback (the Bouncing Ball one), and change the callback condition to:

```
function condition(u,t,integrator) 
    t % 5
end
```

Meaning that I want to trigger the event (defined as function `affect!(integrator)`) every 5 time units. However no event is triggered. I can change `condition` to `(t-5)*(t-10)*(t-15)` etc. but that doesn't generalize to every time point where t is a multiple of 5. What should be put into `condition` instead?

Comment: Use the PeriodicCallback described here: http://docs.juliadiffeq.org/latest/features/callback_library.html#PeriodicCallback-1

Comment: Thank you, I see. And just an extra question, what should I do if I have two callbacks, one of them, say, periodic, and the other one discrete? I see that the ODE solver only accepts one callback argument.

Comment: Use a CallbackSet(cb1,cb2)

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas if these comments answered the question, mind posting as an answer as well?

Comment: The most direct reason that nothing happens is that this formula does not produce a sign change. Try out `(t+2)%5 - 2`. But this could now also trigger at the jumps at `t=3, 8, 13, ...`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to obtain a callback hit at periodic time points is to use the `PeriodicCallback` from the [DiffEqCallbacks.jl](https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqCallbacks.jl) library of pre-built callbacks. In fact, I would highly recommend this since it has a few tricks in there to fix potential floating point issues that can come up. The documentation is [found here](https://diffeqcallbacks.sciml.ai/stable/timed_callbacks/#DiffEqCallbacks.PeriodicCallback), and it is used like:

```
PeriodicCallback((integrator)->integrator.u += 3, 5)
```

which would, at every `5` time units, bump the integrator by 3.